# Error in Territory Name

Tags: apex, community, developer, territory-management, territory

I need to get the Name of the Territory to assign it to a field, but when I try it, it generates an error.

this is my code:

```
List<UserTerritory> myList = [
    select Id, UserId, TerritoryId 
    from UserTerritory
    where UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
    ];

Set<Id> territoryIds = new Set<Id>();
for(UserTerritory terr : myList) {
    territoryIds.add(terr.TerritoryId);
}

List<Territory> territoryN = new List<Territory>([
    select Id, Name
    from Territory
    where Id = :territoryIds
    limit 1
    ]);

System.debug('NAME TERRITORY******' + territoryN.Name);
```

in the `System.debug` I need view the `Name` (`territoryN.Name`)  and the error is:

> Variable does not exist: Name

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code and also run your query in "query editor"

```
List<Territory> territoryN = new List<Territory>([select Id, Name from Territory where Id in: territoryIds]);

 for(Territory tr:territoryN){
system.debug('****territory name******'+tr.name); }
```

Answer (score 0):

`territoryN` is type of `List<Territory>`. Pay attention, that not just `Territory`.  [List](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm) is a container class in Apex. In order to debug names of territiries located in `territoryN` variable, you need to iterate list. Try:

```
for(Territory item :territoryN){
    System.debug('Territory name:' + item.Name);
}
```

instead of

```
System.debug('NAME TERRITORY******' + territoryN.Name);
```